# How can I make my UICollectionViewCell Shadow bleed through to my main View?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

I currently have a UICollectionView (Horizontal) inside a UITableViewCell. I want to add a shadow to the collection view cell, however the shadow gets cut off because of the tableview cell height. Is there any way to make the shadow bleed through?

[image]
(It might be hard to tell from this image, but its getting cut off on the top and bottom)

I have a "background" that clips to the boundaries of the CVCell,

```
background.backgroundColor = .white
background.layer.cornerRadius = 8
background.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
background.layer.shadowRadius = 7
background.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
background.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
background.layer.masksToBounds = true
background.clipsToBounds = false
```

And in my UITableViewCell (Not the cell with the background) I set

```
cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
cell.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Make sure your tableView cell height is equal or greater than to your `collectionView cell height + your shadow radius`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the top and button constraint settings for the `collectionView` cell.

Answer (score 0):

I see you already accepted one answer, but anyway i faced the same issue and adjusting the constraints or content insets (`collectionView.contentInset`) was not an option in my case.

You can simply set

```
collectionView.clipsToBounds = false
```

So subviews whose frames extend beyond the visible bounds of the view aren’t clipped, which applies for shadows.